# Relationship is returning null even when from the database the data exists

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-7, eloquent-relationship

I have been getting an empty array when I query this model relationship for data. I have tried pulling all the data associated with the model from the database and I still do not get the data even though physically the records are in the database. Please can anyone help me fix this?

Here is my model relationship code

```
    public function business()
    {
        return $this->businesses()->first();
    }

   public function businesses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Business::class, 'business_user', 'business_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Here is my resource to pull the data

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'name' => ($this->middle_name) ? "{$this->first_name} {$this->middle_name} {$this->last_name}" : "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}",
            'email' => $this->email,
            'phone_number' => $this->phone_number,
            'next_of_kin' => $this->kin,
            'gender' => $this->gender,
            'image' => $this->image,
           'address' => ($this->business->address) ?: [],
            'business' => ($this->business) ?: [],
            'credits' => ($this->business->credits) ?: [],
            'guarantors' => ($this->business->guarantors) ?: [],
            'verified' => ($this->business->address->verified) ?: [],
            'utility' => ($this->business->address->state_regions) ?: [],
        ];
    }
```

Since the relationship I am querying returns an empty array, all the data depending on it throws an error whenever I try to access them.

Comment: I found the problem with my code:

I did not set the relationship keys in the right order. 

 public function businesses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Business::class, 'business_user', 'business_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

is supposed to be:

 public function businesses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Business::class, 'business_user', 'user_id', 'business_id')->withTimestamps();
    }